# Using Mysql as Embedded application database with Sharp Develop

Tags: c#, mysql, sharpdevelop

Is it possible to use Mysql as SQLlite, Firebird (single databse file) for a local application without installing the server?

I need a database to store the data of my application.thanks

Comment: Unless your application is open sourced under GPL, embedding it inside your app can be a problem if you don't buy commercial license from Oracle. If you would like to pay for that, why not consult Oracle pre-sale directly on your questions :)

Comment: BTW, Firebird does have good records on large databases, http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/case-studies/ so I am not sure why you cannot use it (its license is less restricted than GPL for MySQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an option for you: [libmysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/libmysqld.html).

> The embedded MySQL server library makes it possible to run a full-featured MySQL server inside a client application.

It is written in C/C++, so you should be able to use it in your C# application.

By the way: why not to use SQLite of Firebird? They seems to suit better your requirement.

Comment: thanks! As far as I know, SQLite is not good for big databases, and i never used Firebird

Comment: I have used SQLite in a desktop application with, among the others, a table of 10000 rows. It is not *that* much, but it handles it without any issues, and the application is actually in stressing production since almost 2 years now.

Comment: If the answer satisfies your question, could you flag it as accepted?